# Close/Restore a specific chrome profile?

Tags: google-chrome, crash, forceclose

Is there a way to identify the several instances of "Chrome.exe" for closing/restoring a specific profile?

Scenario: I'm using 2 different Chrome profiles and I'm trying to make an app for one of them which closes it and restores it every few hours (because after a few hours the flash player that it's running starts to hang and there doesn't seem to be any way to prevent that and it doesn't stop hanging until Chrome is restarted).

I've tried using the "Exit" function (Ctrl+Shift+Q) but this closes both profiles.

I've tried chrome://inducebrowsercrashforrealz but this also causes all profiles to stop, not just the profile it's entered on.

I've also tried identifying each window of the profile I want to close (by webpage title in tab), and closing those.. but when I reopen the profile (using the below shortcut) only the last closed window is restored.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --profile-directory="ProfileName"
```

The only way to have all windows of a profile restored seems to be if Chrome crashes on its own or you close the correct "Chrome.exe" tasks from task manager.

Anyone know of a possible solution to this?

Edit:

I tried having the files Last/Current Session/Tabs backed up and overwriting them when I close the 2nd profile.. but this doesn't work because for whatever reason Chrome is still using these files until the 1st profile is closed (even though these files do not belong to the 1st profile).

I'm going to give up, I hate working with Chrome.

Comment: See https://superuser.com/questions/759729/how-to-close-all-tabs-windows-of-a-specific-chrome-user-profile/763206 for a question about how to do this through the user interface (you can't as of Chrome 54), and [this issue](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=130656) to see if the situation changes

Comment: Even changing the files to read-only doesn't stop Chrome writing to them. I backed up all the recently changed files, closed the windows, and copied them back. That worked, but is cumbersome and un-fun...